# Robocopy uses relative path for Source and Destination paths

Tags: team-foundation-server, directory, copy, path, robocopy

I'm trying to use RoboCopy in my TFS Build Template to copy some files, but for some reason it inserts "C:\Windows\system32" in front of my Source and Destination paths, even though I am passing in absolute paths.  I know that the robocopy.exe is stored in "C:\Windows\system32", but how can I make it use my absolute file paths?

Here is the output from my TFS Build Log.  This is the command that gets executed:

```
RoboCopy 'C:\Builds\27\RQ4TeamProject\BuildProcessTests\Binaries' '\\iq-tfsbuild1\buildDrops\BuildProcessTests\0.99.6.32749' /E /XD 'RQ4'
```

And here is the error reported by robocopy:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ROBOCOPY :: Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Started : Thu Jan 24 17:08:47 2013
Source : C:\Windows\system32\'C:\Builds\27\RQ4TeamProject\BuildProcessTests\Binaries'\
Dest : C:\Windows\system32\'\iq-tfsbuild1\buildDrops\BuildProcessTests\0.99.6.32749'\
Files : *.*
○
Exc Dirs : 'RQ4'
○
Options : *.* /S /E /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2013/01/24 17:08:47 ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Source Directory C:\Windows\system32\'C:\Builds\27\RQ4TeamProject\BuildProcessTests\Binaries'\
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Any ideas what is wrong and how I can get it to use JUST the absolute paths I provide?  Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I know this may sound silly but have you tried double quotes (") instead of single quotes (') ?

Comment: Yup, changing to use double quotes fixed my problem. Strange thing is that I tested it using single quotes from the cmd.exe and from powershell and it worked fine. Oh well, it's working now :)

Comment: I'd like to know how you added the RoboCopy step to your build template....see my frustration here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180408/tfs-deploy-without-using-webdeploy

Comment: Hi @ganders I've submitted an answer on your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use double quotes around the paths if necessary, not single quotes.

Comment: Yeah, changing the command to the following fixed the problem. Thanks!

    RoboCopy "C:\Builds\27\RQ4TeamProject\BuildProcessTests\Binaries" "\\iq-tfsbuild1\buildDrops\BuildProcessTests\0.99.6.32749" /E /XD "RQ4"